# iOS: Getting Distance between Locations

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, geocoding

**Please do not mark as duplicate without reading the whole question**

Is there any way to get the length of a *driven* route between two `CLLocation` points in iOS, **without** showing the map?

**Not as the crow flies!!! But like in the MK driving mode**

I cannot use Google since, since I will have to display the results on a Google-Map.

I found this piece of code, but this only works when showing an iOS-Map:

```
-(void)showMapRouteFromCurrentLocation
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D currentUserCoordinate = YourCoordinate;
    //currentUserCoordinate.latitude=  +53.509980;
    //currentUserCoordinate.longitude =  -0.133700;

    MKPlacemark *place = [[MKPlacemark alloc]
                          initWithCoordinate:currentUserCoordinate
                          addressDictionary:nil];


    MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:place];

    NSDictionary *routeOption = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey, nil];

    [mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:routeOption];
}
```

But that is not what I need.

Comment: You can get the distance between the long and lat of two CLLocations, but natively getting the "driving" route persay is much more difficult natively.

Comment: Apparently there is such functionality per se. Like in the Maps App. Isn't it also provided by the SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible using Apple's APIs.  You would need to use a 3rd party system to ask for directions between two points. Like google, but they often have other restrictions, like displaying it on their maps.(as you mentioned).

Not sure if they have similar requirements but you could check out [Map Quest's Api](http://platform.beta.mapquest.com/directions/)

Answer (score 6):

As brainray said, from iOS7, you can do the following:

```
MKDirectionsRequest *routeRequest = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
routeRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile;
[routeRequest setSource:startPoint]; // startPoint is an MKMapItem with the starting lat/long coordinate
[routeRequest setDestination :endPoint]; // endPoint an MKMapItem with the ending lat/long coordinate

MKDirections *routeDirections = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:routeRequest];
[routeDirections calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse * routeResponse, NSError *routeError)
{
    // Check for error and then do something with the route...
    MKRoute *route = routeResponse.routes[0];
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

With iOS7 you [get full directions within the API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH8-SW5)

Take a look at this tutorial [Tutorial](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2013/10/08/ios7-day-by-day-day-13-route-directions-with-mapkit/).

Answer (score 0):

Although Ken gave a good answer, I will also add the way you transform a coordinate into a MKMapItem:

```
+ (void)distanceByRoadFromPoint:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)fromPoint
                        toPoint:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)toPoint
              completionHandler:(MKDirectionsHandler)completionHandler {

    MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
    request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile;

    request.source = [self mapItemFromCoordinate:fromPoint];
    request.destination = [self mapItemFromCoordinate:toPoint];

    MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse * routeResponse, NSError *routeError) {

         MKRoute *route = [routeResponse.routes firstObject];
         CLLocationDistance distance = route.distance;
         NSTimeInterval expectedTime = route.expectedTravelTime;

         //call a completion handler that suits your situation

     }];    

   }


+ (MKMapItem *)mapItemFromCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {

    MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
    MKMapItem *item = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];

    return item;

}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
give latitude2,lang of destination   and latitude,longitude of first place.

this function return distance in kilometer.


  -(double)distanceFilter:(double) latitude2 :(double)lang{
        double distance=(((acos(sin((latitude*M_PI/180)) * sin((latitude2*M_PI/180))+cos((latitude*M_PI/180)) * cos((latitude2*M_PI/180)) * cos(((longitude- lang)*M_PI/180))))*180/M_PI)*60*1.1515*1.609344);

        return distance;
    }
```